# How to select the comma in multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, regex-lookarounds

I have been developing an application for a quite long time now, I started by using rectangular array:

```
int[,] array = new int[900,800]
```

But after giving it some higher values it turned out that it caused a lot of OutOfMemoryException problems, so I decided to replace it with multidimensional array like this:

```
int[][] array /*init stuff*/
```

But after doing so the compiler gave me like 3000 errors (obviously), that would require a lot of time to fix manually, so I started thinking about regular expressions to replace all the ',' with ']['. I want to select the , inside all the array square brackets.
So far I got:

```
(?<=array\[).*,
```

Which selects the ',' right, but also selects the rest of the index like:

```
array[aaa,bbb]
      ^^^^
array[bbbb,ccc]
      ^^^^^
```

Is there a way to select only the ',' like:

```
array[aaa,bbb]
         ^
```

Note: It doesn't have to be 100% perfect, but I want it to work in most of the cases.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you performing the regex search using C# code, or just inside Visual Studio's search dialog?

Comment: The VS search dialog

Comment: What about `(?<=array\[[^,]*),`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression:

```
\[([0-9]+),\s*([0-9]+)\]
```

And replace it with:

```
[$1][$2]
```

This expression matches much less than your current attempt, which will result in less error-prone matching.

Comment: Modified it a little bit and it works perfect. The problem was that it would only select numbers. `array\[(.+),\s*(.+)\]`